# QueryBuilder extract relations like with find() method

Tags: typescript, foreign-keys, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

I have the Post entity each Post have N Comment.
I want to extrat the posts that have most comments, but
I also want to extract the other relations of the Post for example the author (User Entity)

Using the `find()` method I can do:

```
postRepository.find({ relations: ["author", "headingImage"] });
```

but this does not allow me to properly filter the data as I want (GROUP BY).

```
// UP to here I have the top posts now I have to also load the other informations
const data = await Post.createQueryBuilder("post")
  .addSelect("COUNT(comment.id)", "post_comments_cnt")
  .leftJoin("post.comments", "comments")
  .groupBy("post.id")
  .orderBy("post_comments_cnt", "DESC")
  .take(take)
  .skip(skip)
  .getMany();
```

What if I want to load also the relations?

```
const relations = ["author", "headingImage"];

const data = await Post.createQueryBuilder("post")
  ...
  .loadAllRelationIds({ relations })
  .loadRelationCountAndMap("post.commentCount", "course.comments")
  .getMany();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the relations add `leftJoinAndSelect` to the query.

```
const data = await Post.createQueryBuilder("post")
  .addSelect("COUNT(comment.id)", "post_comments_cnt")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("post.author", "author")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("post.headingImage", "headingImage")
  .leftJoin("post.comments", "comments")
  .groupBy("post.id")
  .orderBy("post_comments_cnt", "DESC")
  .take(take)
  .skip(skip)
  .getMany();
```